# ControlValueAccessor Unable to clear input's value

Tags: angular

When the clear button is clicked, the value is reset (I know this because I show required validation message), but the value is still shown in the input element.  How do clear the visual element's text as well as the value?

Custom component markup:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" name="value">
<input type="button" (click)="onClear()" value="clear"/>
```

Typescript

```
  constructor(@Self() @Optional() private control: NgControl) {
    this.control.valueAccessor = this;
  }
 public val: string;
  set value(val: any) {
    if (val !== undefined && this.val !== val) {
      this.val = val;
      this.onChanged(val);
      this.onTouched(val);
    }
  }
  // START ---- ControlValueAccessor interface implementation ---- //
  public disabled: boolean;
  onChanged: any = () => { }
  onTouched: any = () => { }
  writeValue(value: any) {
    this.value = value;
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.onChanged = fn
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    this.onTouched = fn
  }
  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }
  // END ---- ControlValueAccessor interface implementation ---- //

  onClear() {
    this.value = ""; 
  }
```

Comment: do you have a getter as well inside the component? i mean `get value() { return this.val }`

Comment: @yash - I do not.  Is that required for two way binding with [(ngModel)]?

Comment: Yes it is! it's required

Comment: @yash - Didn't realize that!  Seems to work.  Go ahead and add it as the answer so I can accept.

Comment: oh yes, just added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
get value() {
   return this.val;
}
```

`value` is binded to `[(ngModel)]` which is two-way binding so `getter` is required.